# Finding parent objects based on child object value that contains an array of strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My Rails project has two classes, **Events** and **Packages**. Events have many packages, and packages belong to one event. I am wondering if it is possible to return an event only if its package values match all strings in an array, with either a Rails method or raw SQL. I am currently accomplishing this by grabbing all events and searching through them with a few each loops.

```
packages = ["beverage", "food"]
  @events = Event.where('started_at >= ?', DateTime.now).order(started_at: :asc)
  saved_events = []
  @events.each do |event|
    package_counter = 0
    event.packages.each do |package|
      if packages.include? package.kind
        package_counter += 1
        if saved_events.include? event
          break
        end
      end
    end
    if package_counter == packages.length
      saved_events.push(event)
    end
  end

  @events = saved_events
```

With this loop, only events with beverage **AND** food packages will be returned. No events with only beverage or only food packages are returned. I am wondering if it is possible to get the same result with a SQL query, or ActiveRecord method. I have researched for a number of hours to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work in Ruby.  It's a bit costly as it includes all Events and all their packages, but it's easy to understand and maintain, depending on the size of data it may be pretty fast.

```
@packages = ["beverage", "food"]

# includes packages
@events = Event.includes(:packages).where('started_at >= ?', DateTime.now).order(started_at: :asc)

# this will select and return those events who have the package kinds 
# found in a 'packages' array.  The '&' is array intersection
@events.select{|event| (event.packages.map(&:kind) & @packages) == @packages}
```

Comment: This works, except when the packages on the event are not in the same order as @packages. To fix this I added `.order(kind: :asc)` to the `@events.select{|event| (event.packages.map(&:kind) & @packages) == @packages}` line, making it `@events.select{|event| (event.packages.order(kind: :asc).map(&:kind) & @packages) == @packages}`